# Twitter comment's function like Facebook's?

Tags: facebook, twitter, comments

Is there a plugin or api in twitter which can do the exactly comment's function like Facebook? For now, I can only find the search API to show some basic informations. So, I was wondering wether there is something like I just described. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API does not support Facebook-like comments.  This is what the "Reply" and "Retweet" items are for.

Comment: Thanks a lots! Since, there's no way to show comments in twitter, I'll change to use twitter search function to display some useful informations. Thanks again, dude!